# Displaying 3 separate forms on the same page in django

Tags: django, forms, django-models

I'm working on a single page site which is to have 3 different forms on the same page:

- Tour form
- flight form
- bookform

I created the forms using model form, but how do I display the forms such that my site will know which form I'm submitting data to ?

Answer (score 0):

you need pass your forms in your views.py

```
from your_app.forms import TourForm, FlightForm, BookForm
  
def your_view_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tour_form = TourForm(request.POST or None)
        flight_form = FlightForm(request.POST or None)
        book_form = BookForm(request.POST or None)

        # so you have 3 different forms
        if tour_form.is_valid():
            tour_form.save()
            return redirect('some_url')
        elif flight_form.is_valid():
            flight_form.save()
            return redirect('some_url')
        elif book_form.is_valid():
            book_form.is_save()
            return redirect('some_url')
        else:
            return redirect('some_url')
    else:
        tour_form = TourForm()
        flight_form = FlightForm()
        book_form = BookForm()
        context = {
        'tour_form': tour_form,
        'flight_form': flight_form,
        'book_form': book_form
        }
        return render(request, 'your_template_name.html', context)
```

then simply in your template add your forms

```
<form method='post'>
  {% csrf_token %}
   {{ tour_form }}
 <button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>

<form method='post'>
  {% csrf_token %}
   {{ flight_form }}
 <button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>

<form method='post'>
  {% csrf_token %}
   {{ book_form }}
 <button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>
```